# Merging but keeping all observations?

Tags: sas

I have three data sets of inpatient, outpatient, and professional claims. I want to find the number of unique people who have a claim related to tobacco use (1=yes tobacco, 0=tobacco) in ANY of these three data sets.

Therefore, the data sets pretty much are all:

```
data inpatient;
input Patient_ID Tobacco;
datalines;
1 0
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 0
;
run;
```

I am trying to merge the inpatient, outpatient, and professional so that I am left with those patient ids that have a tobacco claim in any of the three data sets using:

```
data tobaccoall;
merge inpatient outpatient professional;
by rid;
run;
```

However, it is overwriting some of the 1's with 0's in the new data set. How do I better merge the data sets to find if the patient has a claim in ANY of the datasets?

Answer (score 7):

When you merge data sets in SAS that share variable names, the values from the data set listed on the right in the `merge` statement overwrite the values from data set to its left. In order to keep each value, you'd want to rename the variables before merging. You can do this in the `merge` statement by adding a `rename=` option after each data set.

If you want a single variable that represents whether a tobacco claim exists in any of the three variables, you could create a new variable using the `max` function to combine the three different values.

```
data tobaccoall;
  merge inpatient    (rename=(tobacco=tobacco_in))
        outpatient   (rename=(tobacco=tobacco_out))
        professional (rename=(tobacco=tobacco_pro));
  by rid;
  tobacco_any = max(tobacco_in,tobacco_out,tobacco_pro,0);
run;
```

Comment: Good answer.  You might add something about using COALESCE or logic statements to get a single variable at the end, also, which is probably what they're really wanting.

Answer (score 0):

If your data were 1=has .=doesn't have (missing), then you could use the `UPDATE` statement, which mostly works like Merge except it wouldn't overwrite nonmissing data with missing.

For example:

```
data inpatient;
input Patient_ID Tobacco;
datalines;
1 .
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 .
;
run;

data outpatient;
input Patient_ID Tobacco;
datalines;
1 1
2 1
3 .
4 .
5 .
;
run;

data want;
  update inpatient outpatient;
  by patient_id;
run;
```